# Connecting Moodle LMS to a Redis server for Moodle caching

Tags: caching, redis, moodle

I am trying to connect a Moodle 3.9 website that's hosted on a Windows Server 2019 computer to a Redis instance running on a Red Hat Redis server so that I can configure Moodle to use Redis for caching, but I'm struggling to connect the Moodle site to that Redis service and get the caching working.

I've referred to https://docs.moodle.org/402/en/Redis_cache_store, but there's a lot of gaps in that documentation...

The 'Installed Cache Stores' page in Moodle shows a green tick for Redis in the Moodle 'Cache administration' page.

The Moodle PHPInfo page shows that the PHP Redis module is installed in PHP.

In Moodle, under 'Site Admin / Plugins / Caching / Configuration', Redis is displayed on the list of Installed Cache Stores.

In Moodle, I've added a Store Instance for Redis and pointed the Server field in that Store Instance to the 'myredisserver.mydomain.com' name of my Redis server. I've also tried the ip address of the Redis server.

Under 'Site Admin / Plugins / Caching / Cache Stores / Redis' I've added my Redis Red Hat Linux server name as 'myredisserver.mydomain.com' in the Test Server Field.

On the Red Hat command line I enter the: `$redis-cli ping` command and Redis responds with `PONG`, implying that Redis is working.

So, why can't Moodle connect to Redis? What am I doing wrong?

Do I need to specify the 6379 port somewhere in the Moodle caching configuration?

Or is it a linux networking issue that I've missed?

Or what else am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

There're are several things to try :
First, where did you pinged your redis server from ? Was it from your moodle server?
Have you enabled the server's firewall to allow them to communicate?

In your steps you don't speak about your php redis setting. You need to modify your php.ini
https://github.com/phpredis/phpredis

```
session.save_handler = redis
session.save_path = "tcp://host1:6379?weight=1, tcp://host2:6379?weight=2&timeout=2.5, tcp://host3:6379?weight=2&read_timeout=2.5"
```

Finally you also need to configure redis in the moodle config.php (which you didn't specify so i guess you didn't). Search for the lines below, they're commented, so uncomment them and fill your config informations:

```
//   Redis session handler (requires redis server and redis extension):
      $CFG->session_handler_class = '\core\session\redis';
      $CFG->session_redis_host = '127.0.0.1';
//      Use TLS to connect to Redis. An array of SSL context options.     Usually:
      $CFG->session_redis_encrypt = ['cafile' => '/path/to/ca.crt']; or...
      $CFG->session_redis_encrypt = ['verify_peer' => false, 'verify_peer_name' => false];
      $CFG->session_redis_port = 6379;                     // Optional.
      $CFG->session_redis_database = 0;                    // Optional, default is db 0.
      $CFG->session_redis_auth = '';                       // Optional, default is don't set one.
      $CFG->session_redis_prefix = '';                     // Optional, default is don't set one.
      $CFG->session_redis_acquire_lock_timeout = 120;      // Default is 2 minutes.
      $CFG->session_redis_acquire_lock_warn = 0;           // If set logs early warning if a lock has not been acquried.
      $CFG->session_redis_lock_expire = 7200;              // Optional, defaults to session timeout.
      $CFG->session_redis_lock_retry = 100;                // Optional wait between lock attempts in ms, default is 100.
                                                           // After 5 seconds it will throttle down to once per second.
```

One last thing : Check if your redis is active with php -m. If not you may have to add a redis.ini in the mods-available folder of you php (but unlikely if it shows in you php info).

Edit:

On debian / ubuntu you should install redis-server

```
apt install redis-server
```

Then edit your redis.conf

```
cp /etc/redis/redis.conf /etc/redis/your-service-name.conf
```

https://redis.io/docs/management/config-file/

and then activate your service

```
systemctl enable redis-server@your-service-name.service
```

Comment: What needs to be done in redis.conf?

Comment: Filling the needed values ? Like the redis server ip in bind, the used port, the pass, ect...